# Basics of conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Currently, I am studying conformal maps i.e. biholomorphic functions. Although I find the theory behind it relatively simple, I do have problems when it comes to showing that a function actually is conformal. Unfortunately, I have not found any good resources so far, thus I am asking this question here.

Could you please hint me into the right direction of, for example, how to show that $f(z)=\sin z$ is a conformal map?

I already know that in $\mathbb C$ the roots of $\sin z$ are the same as in $\mathbb R$, that means $z = k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb Z$. Also, I believe that the representation $$\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$$ could potentially be helpful.

Comment: What are you talking about?  $\sin\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is not bijective (since it is not injective).

Comment: What you say is correct. However, I did not say that I am looking for a conformal map from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C,$ but rather a domain $G$ where $\sin z$ is conformal.